# Can you increase the time SQL Server's Query Optimizer has to find the Best Query Plan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

["...the optimizer is not built to select the best execution plan, but instead to search and find the best possible plan after a set amount of time passes."](https://www.sqlshack.com/query-optimization-techniques-in-sql-server-the-basics/)

Hoping to find a way to override the amount of time the engine uses to find a plan.

The idea being if I had a copy of the database, allowed it to find the best plan, I could then migrate that plan to the production environment.

Related post touched on this, but nothing talks about allowing more time:
[DBMS optimizer - best execution plan, no matter the query's formulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916383/dbms-optimizer-best-execution-plan-no-matter-the-querys-formulation)

Edit 1: Just to be clear, I'm not asking about how the engine works or suggestions on how to get a better plan for a given query based on that plan. I'm just curious as to what happens if I could override an aspect of the engine, in this case, the time it takes to actually perform the optimization. I'll considered this closed since it seems it's not possible to adjust this. If I stumble upon some way to do it, I'll update this post.

Comment: Between using stored procedures, keeping statistics up to date, parameter sniffing and proper index design/maintenance you shouldnt need or want to do this. It also illustrates your lack of understanding of how the optimizer works. You should go take a few online tutorials on this topic. Brent Ozar has some good learning materials but they arent cheap

Comment: Elaborating on Doug's comment - a fully optimized plan for a particular query can change over time depending on many things, so the idea of allowing SQL to spend a lot of extra time to generate the "best possible plan" and then migrating that *fixed* plan to a production environment doesn't make a lot of sense. While it's true that SQL can sometimes come up with a bad plan, letting it think longer doesn't usually make it better. Changing the query structure, adding indexes, or as a last resort adding hints, is a saner option.

Comment: Brian, your idea may sound plausible at first, but unfortunately you can't force the engine to use a specific plan in production. The engine is is constantly adapting the plan to "current" circumstances, and those are changing by the minute. I would suggest you update the histograms of the tables to make sure the engine has accurate information. If the query is still slow, I would get the execution plan and I would ask a new question here, with your specific query and your expectations (they may not be possible).